# Python FTPlib Randomly Errors out - [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, ftplib

Using Python FTPlib to download files from an FTP server. Despite the connection being successful  randomly it's running into Connection refused exception and sometimes downloads partial data.
Unsure why this is occurring and how can I overcome this issue.
Below is my code.

```
class fileTransfer(object):

    def main(self):

        # Arguments
        host        = 'ftp.myHost.com'
        src_dir     = 'Test_Location'
        src_frmt    = 'test_files'
        uname       = 'MyUserName'
        pwd         = 'xxxxxx'
        
        print('*********************** File Transfer **************************')
        print('   Host name       : ' + host)
        print('   FTP Location    : ' + src_dir)
        print('   File Pattern    : ' + src_frmt)
       
        # Call the function to Transfer Files
        filesDownload(host,uname,pwd,src_dir,src_frmt)
        

def filesDownload(host,uname,pwd,src_dir,src_frmt):
    # Connection to FTP 
    try:
        print("INFO: Connecting to FTP...")
        ftps = FTP_TLS('{0}'.format(host))
        ftps.login(user = '{0}'.format(uname), passwd = '{0}'.format(pwd))
        print("INFO: Connection to FTP Successful")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    
    # Change FTP Location
    print("INFO: Changing Directory")
    ftps.cwd(src_dir)
    # List of files to download based on source pattern 
    files = ftps.nlst(src_frmt + '*')
    print("INFO: Number of files to download - " + str(len(files)) + "\nINFO: Files to download are - \n" + '\n'.join(files))
    
    # Download files
    print("INFO: Initiating files download")
    try:
        for f in files:
            with open(f, 'wb') as fh:
                ftps.retrbinary('RETR ' + f, fh.write)
        print("\nINFO: Files Downloaded to local successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


#  Main Function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(" ~~ Running fileTransfer ~~ ")
try:
    fileTransfer().main()
except Exception as e:
    print(' ##### Error running fileTransfer ##### ')
    raise Exception(e)
```

The error I get :

```
 ~~ Running fileTransfer ~~ 
*********************** File Transfer **************************
   Host name       : ftp.myHost.com
   FTP Location    : Test_Location
   File Pattern    : test_files
INFO: Connecting to FTP...
INFO: Connection to FTP Successful
INFO: Changing Directory
INFO: Number of files to download - 3
INFO: Files to download are - 
test_files_1.xlsx
test_files_2.xlsx
test_files_3.xlsx
INFO: Initiating files download
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

It appears that the connection is successful but the connection refused occurs while downloading the files.

Can someone suggest what could be the issue and how could this be resolved.

Thanks..

Comment: Try experimenting with [set_pasv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.set_pasv)

Comment: Tried bu no luck.....